# How to move entity from one database to another using openjpa?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

I am trying to move entity objects from one database to another without success. Example code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfFrom = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(fromPU);
EntityManager emFrom = emfFrom.createEntityManager();

EntityManagerFactory emfTo = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(toPU);
EntityManager emTo = emfTo.createEntityManager();

//Code to create sql for example 'select row from order row' where order is an entity

Query q = emFrom.createQuery(sql);
for(Object o: q.getResultList()) {
   emFrom.detach(o);
   emTo.persist(entity);
}
```

This results in:

> Exception in thread "main"       >org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Attempt to persist detached object "Order-1".  If this is a new instance, make sure any version and/or auto-generated primary key fields are null/default when persisting.
>   FailedObject: Order-1
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2628)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2571)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2554)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2458)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1077)
>     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:716)

I have tried to use merge instead of persist but no rows are saved in the database. I have also tried to set the id field to null using reflection (since its private) like this:

```
Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(o, null);
```

But no luck. I have not been able to set the version field to null since it is a long while the id filed is a Long. I dont know if that would help.

I am using java 7 and openjpa 2.2. Any ideas on how to move entities would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Nice problem. Could you try to use copy constructor and persist the new instance? I think that current instance is already instrumented JPA to associate it with some db session.

Comment: I can not change the source code of the entity classes, only look at source. (Big corporations FTW!)

Comment: Try to create object with same attributes and persist it.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing your JPA provider because it will have wrapped your entity in a proxy with information detailing what kind of state it is relative to the database (e.g. it knows its loaded successfully and hasn't been amended) so calling 'save' using a different underlying database won't make sense.

You need to create a copy of the object (essentially field by field) and then persist it so your JPA provider thinks its an insert, not an update.

Now you might say you don't want to copy every field - its error prone and would take a while.  A good trick is to convert into JSON then back out again into the new object.

Have a look at Googles GSON:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

for example:

```
final SomeEntity oldInstance = new SomeEntity("hello");
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final String json = gson.toJson(oldInstance);
final SomeEntity newInstance = gson.fromJson(json, oldInstance.getClass());
```

You'll need getters/setters and non-final fields for doing this as the JSON librarys use reflection over the class, otherwise you'll have to hand-code some kind of copy constructor or builder to do it field by field

Comment: I was looking for e generic way to move an jpa entity from one db to another. I fell back to add a copy constructor to all my entities. Gson isn't great for circular references and I don't what to add yet another jar to my project. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Jackson is pretty good for circular refs - see @JsonBackReference.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I found two solution for that . 
**First : clear OpenJPA State**

```
/*
 * Method 1 : clear OpenJPA State
 */
 Field field = car.getClass().getDeclaredField("pcStateManager");
 field.setAccessible(true);
 field.set(car, null);
 car.setId(null);
 EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
 transaction.begin();
 entityManager.persist(car);
 transaction.commit();
```

**and in second solution you can use dozer** and create new instance of entity , remember you must exclude @Id field when map entity instances

```
List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
mappingFiles.add("dozer-mappings.xml");
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.setMappingFiles(mappingFiles);
```

you can find more details about the solution on my [Github sample](https://github.com/aminarab/context-switch)